# Show mysql data in php using the $_GET['id'] coming in from the URL

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm getting the 'id' from the URL, but I can't seem to use it to select other pieces of data from the same row.  I'm trying to show Film_Title (the name of the row in MySQL) using the Film_ID.  In this case the Film_ID is coming in from the URL like this: /film.php?id=58.

How do I use that id to select Film_Title?  Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = trim($_GET['id']); 
    $Film_Title = trim($_POST['Film_Title']);

    $sql = "SELECT Film_Title FROM Films WHERE Film_ID=?";

    require_once 'includes/MySQL.php';  
    require_once 'includes/db.php';

    $db = new MySQL($dbconfig['host'], $dbconfig['user'], $dbconfig['password'], $dbconfig['database']);
    $stm = $db->dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($id, $Film_Title));
    echo "<h3>film record $Film_Title has been selected</h3>";

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to bind the $id to Film_ID?

Comment: You are putting only a `?` in your query but two elements in your `execute()` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting only a ? in your query but two elements in your execute() array. I prefer to put the query just before where I'm using it, or just inside the prepare, since it's closer to the execute thus less error-prone. Besides, you were not fetching your data.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = trim($_GET['id']); 
  $Film_Title = trim($_POST['Film_Title']);

  require_once 'includes/MySQL.php';    
  require_once 'includes/db.php';

  $db = new MySQL($dbconfig['host'], $dbconfig['user'], $dbconfig['password'], $dbconfig['database']);
  $stm = $db->dbConn->prepare("SELECT Film_Title FROM Films WHERE Film_ID=?");
  // There's only one placeholder, so only 1 element in the array is needed
  $stm->execute(array($id));
  // Also you need to fetch the results
  $result = $stm->fetch();
  echo "<h3>film record " . $result['Film_Title'] . " has been selected</h3>";
  }
```

Comment: it worked!!! thank you so much!  I can't believe I was working on that for three hours! Now what should I do if I want to put more than one datum, would that mean more array items?

Comment: Don't worry, the first times it'll be slow or difficult, but after one year or so practicing it'll take less than five minutes to do the code you posted (:

Answer (score -1):

$sql = "SELECT Film_Title FROM Films WHERE Film_ID=$id";